# Internet Connections Ubuntu 12.04 Server with Unity GUI

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection, static-ip

I am very new to all this and thought I'd have a look at ubuntu with the hope of it running my server.

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 Server which went fine, I then installed Unity again this was all fine.

I can access the GUI fine but my one problem is Internet Connection.

It works fine, I can access the internet and everything but I can't view System Setting>Network as it says 'The system network service are not compatible with this version'

I also can't see any network connections or if I click on edit connections it opens fine but I can't actually edit or add anything as it is all shaded out.

I was trying to assign my server a static ip address

Does anyone have any idea what's up with this. Like it said the internet works fine.

Any solutions or advice for this complete newbie would be much appreciated.

Many thanks
Luke

Answer (score 1):

you can give the static ip to your system.

type as `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

there you will some lines and with dhcp at the end point .for example like this

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Now you have replace `dhcp` with `static`. Then mention all other contents like netmask,gateway etc .for example

```
address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
netmask XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file . so up to this we have setup a static connection and now we have to mention Information about DNS server . to do that type this

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

then type there as

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Those are the better DNS servers i know , if you know or have you anything good then place the address after nameserver .

Then again <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Now you have to restart your Network manager .

type this command to restart

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Then check it out . I am sure it will for you . all the best .

Comment: Completely different issue but do you know much about Samba? I am trying to configure it but it will not accept my password and I am confused as there should be no other passwords on this server as I've just set it up! No worries if you don't know as I'll post it up here in a bit. Once again thank you

Comment: you're welcome ! actually this is the way  how to setup a static IP connection in Ubuntu servers where there is no GUI . i  gave this because i read this my amigo " I was trying to assign my server a static ip address " from your question.